# Pasting large files

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, ubuntu, paste

I'm writing a plugin to handle file uploads. I thought implementing a paste feature would be awesome (how often have you event just wanted to paste instead of having to open a photo editor and then save it as file and then upload, but I digress). What I'm doing so far works, except for when the file being pasted becomes too big. I cannot tell you what size 'too big' is, because I'm doing a screenshot selection and saving it to the clipboard.

My current code looks like

```
document.getElementById('AJS').onpaste = function (e) {
    var items = (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData).items,
    blob = items[0].getAsFile();
    if (blob && blob.type.match(T.s.accept) && T.currentlength < T.s.maxFiles) {
        T.process(param1, param2, param3, param4, items[0].getAsFile());
    }
};
```

T.process

```
T.process = function (file, i, changing, target, pasteblob) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function (e) {
        var blob = pasteblob || new Blob([e.target.result], {type: file.type});
        var dataURL = (win.URL || win.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
        var index = changing ? i : T.currentlength;
        var filedata =  {};
        if (file.type.match('image/*')) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                // Doing stuff
            };
            img.src = dataURL;
        } else {
            // Doing stuff
        }
    };
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(pasteblob || file);
};
```

For larger files, the blob from `blob = items[0].getAsFile()` returns a size of 0. Has anyone else experienced this problem and how have you been able to overcome it?

Note: I'm using the latest Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: And your question is...?  No idea what the specific issue is either.  What __specifically__ is going wrong?  "it doesn't work sometimes" isn't enough detail.

Comment: And why are you trying to turn a `Blob` into a `Blob` using `FileReader`?  Just turn the pasted `Blob` into an object URL, no need for all of these needless conversions, checks, and uses of `FileReader`.

Comment: @RayNicholus `T.process` handles both organic file input data and paste data (and has a lot of code missing that isn't relevant to the question). The paste data is a new addition I've been working on for the last hour or so. I thought I was *very* clear when I said '*What can I do to make it work for large files?*'

Comment: What is failing for "large files"?  What is going wrong?  Are you expecting us to run and debug your code for you?

Comment: @RayNicholus If I wanted debugging I would have copied a link to codepen or whatever. For larger screenshots, the blob created using `items[0].getAsFile()` returns a blob of length 0, which therefore cannot load any data. All I want to know is if anyone has had this problem and found a solution to it.

Comment: "For larger screenshots, the blob created using items[0].getAsFile() returns a blob of length 0".  That is what I was looking for.  I would include this in your question.  I've never run into this issue myself.  Just tested a paste of a 3 MB image using my own paste handler code, without issue.  Are you seeing the issue for files larger than 3 MB?

Comment: My apologies, I just tested a screenshot, and the blob returned 0 bytes for a file of 487Kb. I'm using Ubuntu Chrome, so this may be a factor

Comment: Could be.  Just pasted a 50 MB file without issue as well.  I've been testing on OSX Chrome.  A quick search in the chromium bug tracker didn't reveal anything.  If you can distill this into a very simply test case, you may want to look into opening a chromium bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't have any references to anyone other than my own personal research into the matter, it seems as if there is a bug on the Ubuntu version of chrome that prevents users copying and pasting using the native JS api. If you attempt to paste a screenshot in a GMail message using Ubuntu Chrome, you get an error, but this error doesn't come up in any other version of chrome. It was also the same for my code above as well. I tested it on native windows and OS X environments running chrome that were pointing to my machine, and pasting using this script worked just fine!